# Pandas. Разделить DataFrame по нескольким условиям

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Помогите пожалуйста! Есть DF

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Code":["001","002","002","003","001","001","003"],
                       "Products":["Name1","Name2","Name2","Name3","Name1","Name1","Name3"],
                       "Qty":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
                       "Person":["Mr_X","Mr_X","Mr_X","Mr_Y","Mr_X","Mr_Y","Mr_Y"],
                       "Price":["50","100","100","75","50","50","75"]})

  Code Products Qty Person Price
0  001    Name1   1   Mr_X    50
1  002    Name2   1   Mr_X   100
2  002    Name2   1   Mr_X   100
3  003    Name3   1   Mr_Y    75
4  001    Name1   1   Mr_X    50
5  001    Name1   1   Mr_Y    50
6  003    Name3   1   Mr_Y    75
```

Имеющийся DF нужно разделить на несколько, по условиям: для каждой Person, не может быть больше 2х  единиц QTY, одного Code и общая сумма не должна превышать 200.
в данном примере, что хотелось бы получить
df1

```
  Code Products Qty Person Price  
0  001    Name1   2   Mr_X   100
1  002    Name2   1   Mr_X   100
```

df2

```
  Code Products Qty Person Price
0  002    Name2   1   Mr_X   100
```

df3

```
  Code Products Qty Person Price
0  001    Name1   1   Mr_Y    50
1  003    Name3   2   Mr_Y   150
```

Comment: Условие не вполне корректно. Ваши условия "для каждой Person, не может быть больше 2х единиц QTY, одного Code и общая сумма не должна превышать 200" полностью соответствуют исходному фрейму, если разделить его построчно.

Comment: проблема в исходном файле в том, что количество строк вариативно, от 1 до 100к, и я не совсем понимаю, условия цикла, для проверки исходного DF и разделения его.